# ASP.NET Custom Error Pages returns 500

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

When I configure my `Web.config` file like this:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="err_404.html">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="err_404.html" />
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="err_403.html" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

I get a 500.19 internal server error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you tell more about error description? 500.19 response code can be received when web.config hasn't permissions for IIS_IUSRS group for example.

Comment: @AndrewOrlov It says that the server configuration file is invalid.

Comment: It's really hard to say anything about error with this short excerpt. For now I can see only misplaced closing `</configuration>`. Can you show your whole web.config? Without sensitive data of course.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error statusCode="500.19" redirect="~/Views/ErrorMessages/Oops.cshtml" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="500.19" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="500.19" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="~/Views/ErrorMessages/Oops.cshtml"
         responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```